Does Psalm 104:4 imply that HaShem created the angels on Day 2?
Psalms 104:4

He makes his angels spirits, his ministers a flame of fire.

The context here appears to surround the Genesis creation narrative, and fits between the light of Day 1 and the appearing of dry land of Day 3.
The angels are not mentioned anywhere in Genesis despite the fact that they must have been created somewhere within it, and this may be revealed in the Psalm 104:4.
Does the position of this passage imply that HaShem created the angels on Day 2, when the firmament was set to divide the waters of heaven and earth, between the first light and the dry land?

Yes, Bereshit Rabbah records that angels were created on day 2, and quotes this verse.

When were the angels created? R. Johanan said: They were created on the second day, as it is written, Who layest the beams of Thine upper chambers in the waters (Ps. 104, 3), followed by, Who makest the spirits Thine angels (ib. 4) [Translation: ... Under The Editorship Of Rabbi Dr. H. Freedman, B.A., Ph.D. and Maurice Simon]


Thank you, Rabbi. Are there any other supporting scriptures for that revelation? I'm just curious, and thank you again.

@OneGodOneLord pleasure! No, I am not aware of any other verses in Tanach that are sourced in the tradition as implying or revealing that angels were created on day 2

Wait, there is an argument in the midrash 2nd and 5th. Can we also say that Satan was created on the 6th as tov meod?

@YDJ that midrash you reference (Bereshit Rabbah 9:7, Rabbi Nachman bar Shmuel bar Nachman in the name of Rav Shmuel bar Nachman) doesn't explicitly say that the yetzer hara was made on the 6th day, and I don't really think it would contradict the teachings of Rabbi Yochanan and Rabbi Chanina above if it was. The midrashim, and commentaries, associate the yetzer hara's tov meod with the influence on man that builds the world, including love, as well as jealousy, competition etc. Its influence on man began on day 6. The yetzer hara/satan is not tov meod, that's an אתמהא of R Shmuel bar Nachman
